# Lot of Netty Threads in Native.epollWait

Tags: java, performance, netty

I am initializing Netty Thread Pool like this:-
`bossGroup = new EpollEventLoopGroup(1);`
`workerGroup = new EpollEventLoopGroup(1);`
This creates more than 80 threads for a single application running on a VM allocated with 40  vCPUs.Is there a way that these threads can be reduced? 
As it is not expected that the number of server and clients to increase?
Using Netty final 4.1.32

Comment: Using Netty 4.1.32 Final

Comment: Netty will only use 2 * available processors if you pass 0 to that constructor (or one of its overloads that itself passes 0), so I don't believe that's what you're using. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I shall certainly try and provide a reproducible example. However if the app had those two lines of code as pasted above for initializing the EpollEventLoopGroup -- then for an application running with 40 vCPU - is it possible to give a rough estimate on how many threads will be in epollWait0 and having a stack trace as given in the next message

Comment: io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.epollWait0 (bci=0, native method)
io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.epollWait (Native.java:114, bci=19, c2)
io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.epollWait (EpollEventLoop.java:253, bci=99, c2)
io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run (EpollEventLoop.java:278, bci=73, c2 osr - bci: 0)
io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run (SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:909, bci=44, interpreter)
io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run (FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30, bci=4, interpreter)
java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:748, bci=11, interpreter)

Comment: There should only be 2, one of each group. (Maybe you're setting up more that you aren't showing us.)

Answer (score 0):

The code you showed will only create 2 `EpollEventLoop` instances and so only two Threads will end up in `epollWait(...)`. You must execute this code multiple times or have a different place where you configure it differently to end up with more Threads. Another possibility is that you execute it multiple times but miss to call `shutdownGracefully()` on the `EpollEventLoopGroup` once you are done using it.